# when I use boost::this_thread::sleep, what happens to its pid directory in /proc/{pid}?

Tags: c++, linux

I am having a program which keeps track of other processes whether they are terminated or still running with respect to pid and I do this looking their pid directory in /proc.

But when a process goes in sleep, is it like its directory is gone becoz its being my watching process show it as terminated.

Comment: I think if you actually looked in that directory, you'd find it *isn't* gone. So there's probably a bug in your program regarding how it judges whether a program is running. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your spelling, no - if you're running linux, your sleeping process will still show up in /proc regardless. You can try this by creating a program "sleep.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5000
```

then run it in the background

```
./sleep.sh &
```

and then

```
ls -l /proc/$!
```

$! is the pid of the process in the background which is sleeping.

Separately - tracking whether a process is alive or dead by polling /proc is generally a bad idea. It's entirely possible that when the process you're tracking disappears, another one with precisely the same pid will start up.